# txt vs entries in DNS TXT record

Tags: php, dns

I wonder what's the difference between txt field and entries field in a TXT record returned by a DNS query, using PHP's dns_get_record.

For example, if I call dns_get_record on 's1._domainkey.mydomain.com' for the TXT record, I get:

```
entries: ["k=rsa; t=s; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCnVgd0NyrRE261IIiPqi+0H1baNyKcdj8Kea/VlSP4exzvKx8pJ01EWMwd094FV/6OCBIf7KGKgowMnWl3tW3Z5d++uZHkdgF+6xg7b9PynmX/NTo2kx92hlGgegwyulF5B7d2FM0doaCeoO4rD05jZzwi3cXx/156Gg9Xwd/Z/QIDAQAB"]

txt: "k=rsa; t=s; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCnVgd0NyrRE261IIiPqi+0H1baNyKcdj8Kea/VlSP4exzvKx8pJ01EWMwd094FV/6OCBIf7KGKgowMnWl3tW3Z5d++uZHkdgF+6xg7b9PynmX/NTo2kx92hlGgegwyulF5B7d2FM0doaCeoO4rD05jZzwi3cXx/156Gg9Xwd/Z/QIDAQAB"
```

The code that produced this result is:

```
function retrieve_spf_record($domain) { 
    $txtRecords = dns_get_record($domain, DNS_TXT); 
    foreach ($txtRecords as $txtRecord) { 
        if (startsWith($txtRecord['txt'], 'v=spf1')) { 
            return $txtRecord; 
        } 
    } 
    return FALSE; 
}
```

It seems to me that entries is identical to txt in this case. But I guess they can server different purposes in some other scenarios, otherwise there would be no point having both of them.

So why are there both txt and entries fields? Could this be related to the scenario where a value is too long (like over 512B, for example), so that it's split and stored in entries?

If the above guess is correct, then the complete value of such a TXT record would be all entries concatenated, and the txt field should be ignored -- is this correct?

Any explanation would be welcome. Thanks!

Update: here is what PHP's dns_get_record returns on 'cisco.com':

```
Array
(
    [host] => cisco.com
    [class] => IN
    [ttl] => 3158
    [type] => TXT
    [txt] => v=spf1 ip4:173.37.147.224/27 ip4:173.37.142.64/26 ip4:173.38.212.128/27 ip4:173.38.203.0/24 ip4:64.100.0.0/14 ip4:72.163.7.160/27 ip4:72.163.197.0/24 ip4:144.254.0.0/16 ip4:66.187.208.0/20 ip4:173.37.86.0/24 ip4:64.104.206.0/24 ip4:64.104.15.96/27 ip4:64.102.19.192/26 ip4:144.254.15.96/27 ip4:173.36.137.128/26 ip4:173.36.130.0/24 mx:res.cisco.com mx:sco.cisco.com include:spf.protection.outlook.com ~all
    [entries] => Array
        (
            [0] => v=spf1 ip4:173.37.147.224/27 ip4:173.37.142.64/26 ip4:173.38.212.128/27 ip4:173.38.203.0/24 ip4:64.100.0.0/14 ip4:72.163.7.160/27 ip4:72.163.197.0/24 ip4:144.254.0.0/16 ip4:66.187.208.0/20 ip4:173.37.86.0/24
            [1] =>  ip4:64.104.206.0/24 ip4:64.104.15.96/27 ip4:64.102.19.192/26 ip4:144.254.15.96/27 ip4:173.36.137.128/26 ip4:173.36.130.0/24 mx:res.cisco.com mx:sco.cisco.com include:spf.protection.outlook.com ~all
        )

)
```

Comment: Hmm I don't get anything like the same output from `dns_get_record`. I just get an indexed array of records, as per the documentation... `"This function returns an array of associative arrays"`

Comment: USD Matt, it is an array of array. Please check the complete dump of the array in the update.

Comment: The update gives your answer, `entries` is a list of the individual DNS entries, and `txt` is the entire set as one. I suspected that but could not verify as my own tests produced completely different output. I'm still not sure why you get a different format unless it has been changed in recent versions and not updated in php documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dns_get_record` returns an *array of associative arrays*.

If you run

```
 var_dump(dns_get_record("s1._domainkey.mydomain.com"));
```

what do you get?

The output you originally got might be an artifact caused by trying to print out an array of associative arrays interpreted as some simpler type.

---

In both cases, the "entries" strings are all less than 255 octets (ASCII characters), which is the maximum length of the generic DNS TXT record.

But since the entire DKIM TXT record in your original example is less than 255 octets, there would be only one string in the "entries" sub-array.

In the `cisco.com` example, the total length of the DKIM record is 405 octets, so it must be presented in DNS as two TXT records, as per [RFC 4408](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4408.txt). And the two strings in the `entries` sub-array are both less than 255 octets long, so it looks like your maximum length theory is correct.

The `txt` element of the main associative array contains the TXT records already concatenated for your convenience. If you need the raw individual TXT records for some reason, the `elements` sub-array can provide them for you.

Comment: I believe the output I got was untampered. Please see the update.

Comment: Are you definitely running purely this function, or using some library? I've retested on PHP5 & 7, both produce a simple array of associative arrays as documented.

Comment: My code is like this: function retrieve_spf_record($domain) {
    $txtRecords = dns_get_record($domain, DNS_TXT);
    foreach ($txtRecords as $txtRecord) {
        if (startsWith($txtRecord['txt'], 'v=spf1')) {
            return $txtRecord;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

Comment: I am not using any other library.

Comment: Ok so you're going through the returned records and only returning the first entry that matches an spf record, which is why your output doesn't match the `dns_get_record` docs. Fortunately I don't believe the SPF spec allows for more than one record so you are probably ok with just returning the first.

Comment: @lgc_ustc: I took the liberty of adding your code to the original post, with formatting applied. Also see my updated answer.